# How to deal with the fast rate of play online

Tags: online

I recently tried playing online for the first time and I was astonished by how fast it was.  More than one time my timer actually ran out before I could figure out what I wanted to do, and I was auto-folded, one time in the middle of trying to set the amount for a pre-flop raise with pocket pairs.

I feel like I don't have time to even try to calculate odds because the play is too fast, and then I get flustered and can't even think what possible board combinations there could be, and then at the showdown I am not even following what every player had before the cards go back into the virtual deck.  Is this a usual for players new to online play?  Should I try a different site that might not be as fast? Should I just give up trying to play online because I'm slow?

Comment: It depends on the tables or even the game types (play money?); I don't know where are you playing at but most sites have some information on every table before you enter, like hands/hour. Perhaps you played zoom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're playing a zoom or rush table where you only have a few seconds. You will get used to it pretty quickly but to ease yourself into it just try play a single table, maybe for a lower stake than you're used to playing at until you adjust.

You will find you get much quicker and these decisions once you get used to the shift from live to online. Just keep at it and ease yourself into it. Also the online sites all(pretty sure all of them anyway) offer play money which you can use until you get used to the speed. That way you won't be risking anything while you transition from live to online.

Comment: yeah, i'm not going to play for money until i'm comfortable with the playing environment; also, i'm only playing one table.  i'll try playing for lower stakes, and maybe try other sites to see if they offer more selection with regards to how much time you have to make decisions.